# Two traffic observations and questions

Tags: discussion, statistics, recent-activity

The MathOverflow traffic (page views, visits, new visits) shows steady and possibly increasing activity
over the last $2+$ yrs. The chart below runs from 2019-Jul-07 on the left and 2021-Nov-04 on the right. More than $2\frac{1}{4}$ years. One can see predictable seasonal variations—diminished activity near
Christmas, a trough in the summers.

Two points:

- I would think that MO activity would decrease over the years,
  as more and more fundamental questions get asked and answered. But
  that does not seem to be the case. If anything, traffic is (slowly) increasing.
- Something happened around 3Aug2020.

I'd appreciate any comments/speculations that explain these two observations.

[image: TrafficChart]

Comment: I think the hypothesis that MO is used to answer fundamental questions may not be a natural one.  To the extent that it is, I think MO users, me among them, are so eager to ask their neat questions that they aren't very thorough about checking for duplicates, so that lots of fundamental questions get repeatedly re-asked.

Comment: Why should questions connected to research decrease over time? The research output of mathematicians seems to be going up, overall.

Comment: Maybe ([meta-tag:statistics]) could be a suitable tag here?

Comment: You write "Two questions". But there is no question below.

Comment: @YCor: The two questions are to explain the slight rise, and the anomaly in August 2020.

Comment: I sort of guess this is what you want to ask. But these are not formulated as questions.

Comment: @YCor: Revised to make it clearer. Thanks.

Comment: Big spikes should be: questions mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: Note that summers occur around January/February in the Southern Hemisphere - not sure how many Southern Hemisphere users or visitors we have here though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is it possible that the question "[Issue UPDATE: in graph theory, different definitions of edge crossing numbers - impact on applications?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/366765)" might be partly responsible for the peak?

- This question now has 92k views.
- In the [revision history](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/366765/revisions) and the [timeline](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/366765/timeline) you can see that it became a HNQ on July 28.
- A link to this question was posted on reddit r/math on August 4: [User on MathOverflow realizes he made an early crucial misunderstanding on the core content of his Ph.D. thesis 2 weeks before submission. Other users come to the rescue and he is able to resolve the issue.](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/i3au6w/user_on_mathoverflow_realizes_he_made_an_early/)
- David Roberts pointed out in a comment that it was posted also on [Hacker News](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_News) on August 4: [Math Overflow users resolve PhD thesis crisis](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=24049428). (I am not familiar with that site, but if he says that this will generate a lot of traffic, I am willing to take his word for it.)
- It is the question Posted in 2020 with the most views, see [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1508208/top-viewed-question-between-two-days?Date1=2020-01-01&Date2=2021-01-01), [search](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=views%3A50000+created%3A2020-01-01..2021-01-01)
- If we check Wayback Machine, we see 18k views [on August 4](https://web.archive.org/web/20200804143043/https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366765/issue-update-in-graph-theory-different-definitions-of-edge-crossing-numbers) and 81k views [on August 5](https://web.archive.org/web/20200805162610/https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366765/issue-update-in-graph-theory-different-definitions-of-edge-crossing-numbers).

If we notice a smaller peak a few days before that, that one might perhaps be connected with the question "[What are the benefits of writing vector inner products as $\langle u, v\rangle$ as opposed to $u^T v$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/366070)". It had 8k views [on July 21](https://web.archive.org/web/20200721225642/https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366070/what-are-the-benefits-of-writing-vector-inner-products-as-langle-u-v-rangle) and 43k views on [July 24](https://web.archive.org/web/20200724182740/https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366070/what-are-the-benefits-of-writing-vector-inner-products-as-langle-u-v-rangle).

Notice that from SEDE we can get ViewCount for each question - we see CreationDate of that question, but we do not know how the views were distributed over time. Some related queries; [Sum of ViewCount per day](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1508209/sum-of-viewcounts-per-day?Date1=2020-01-01&Date2=2021-01-01#graph), [Top viewed question per day](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1508207/top-viewed-question-per-day?Date1=2020-01-01&Date2=2021-01-01).

On MO there are 18 questions [with 100k+ views](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=views%3A100000) and [23 questions with 90k+ views](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=views%3A90000).
Here is a SEDE query [showing question with the most views](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1508211/questions-with-most-views). I would not be surprised if you found at least some  peaks in activity near other highly viewed questions. You could also check [other highly voted reddit posts related to MO](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/search/?q=mathoverflow&restrict_sr=1&sr_nsfw=&sort=top) to see whether they lead to highly viewed questions and whether you can find some peaks in the traffic near them. (This particular reddit thread is shown as the top in the linked search, with score 2.2k.)

I would guess that it depends a bit on the size of the site and on the total number of questions per day whether a single question can significantly change the statistics for the whole site. Here are some [stats from 2020 for MO](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1508212/most-viewed-question-vs-sum-of-views). If you look at [the percentage of views contributed by the top question](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1508213/most-viewed-question-vs-sum-of-views-only-percentage#graph), on MO it was in 2020 quite often above 50%. If you compare this [with Mathematics in 2020](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1508213/most-viewed-question-vs-sum-of-views-only-percentage#graph), you never see a number above 30%.

Comment: Oh, good catch on that question that was posted to Reddit. I remember that question, and it's exactly the sort of quasi-clickbait that gets people excited.

Comment: A commenter points out that it was also linked [on HackerNews](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=24049428) on Aug 4, which would have driven a lot of traffic here. There are 653 upvotes on that post on HN, and 127 comments.

Comment: HackerNews is the equal-sixth-highest referring site for MathOverflow in the past month, if that gives any context to how much traffic we get from there without spikes. All the higher-listed sites are MO itself or stackexchange sites. Overall, new visits went up by a factor about 6 on Aug 4th 2020 compared to the previous day, and total page visits more than doubled.

Comment: And note the [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/i3au6w/user_on_mathoverflow_realizes_he_made_an_early/) has net 2181 upvotes, which is very high for r/math, so it got a lot of attention.